# Is it possible in django model form to show certain fields if user select a related field?

Tags: django

I have a user model field with choices asking about employment, if person select the choice employed then only I want to show fields asking about employer details in user inerface, any possibilities? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

django's native forms do not, by default, have this ability.  this is generally accomplished by adding the appropriate client-side controls into the form's template; e.g. using javascript to show/hide some fields based on another field's value.  this is commonly accomplished [using javascript](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-cookbook/9781449390211/ch09s09.html) or in some cases [even pure css](https://css-tricks.com/exposing-form-fields-radio-button-css/).

if you're dealing with a multi-step form across multiple pages or if you know in advance what the value that might include/remove fields is, you can override the form's `__init__` method to manipulate its `self.fields` property to add or remove fields as desired when the form is initially being generated.

good luck!

Comment: Thank you for reply, since I use model form, how I can select one particular field to show/hide or pop up using js/jquery?

Comment: 2 options:  if you're just outputting the whole form with a single template tag, you can view the page source of the form to determine the final html layout and use whatever the desired fields' html container class/id to show/hide wih js.  otherwise you can manually generate the form in your template by calling each form field's template tag individually, giving you complete control over the html layout.  see [the django forms documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates) for more :)

Comment: Thank you so much.